# Creating a Mutex throws a DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: .net, mutex

I'm trying to create a [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01985e8f.aspx), but when I call the constructor I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`! Why is a mutex trying to access the filesystem, and how do I know what is a valid path? Is there any particular directory the mutex should be placed in, and how does that correspond to the name?

EDIT: I'm using the `Mutex(bool, string)` overload, and the exception is:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '<mutex name>'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.Threading.Mutex.<>c__DisplayClass3.<.ctor>b__0(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew, MutexSecurity mutexSecurity)
at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)
```

Comment: What constructor are you using, and what are the details of the exception?

Comment: Yikes.  This question was posted just 15 minutes ago and already it's the second result in a Google search for "mutex directorynotfoundexception".  That's quick crawling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not find a part of the path" error while creating Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714120/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-error-while-creating-mutex)

Comment: Wow! This DirectoryNotFoundException is completly misleading.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ah, found what the problem was. My mutex name had `\` in it, which windows was interpreting as a path character. Running:

```
mutexName = mutexName.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '_');
```

fixes the problem

Comment: I would suggest replacing any instances of any of the characters from [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) (e.g. `/` is also invalid).

Comment: It's not really a path character, [there's a full explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20714164/1729885). All characters except backslash are valid, because of Kernel Object Namespaces.