# "Could not find a part of the path" error while creating Mutex

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mutex

I'm baffled by this, can someone tell me why, when I call:

```
using (Mutex mtx = new Mutex(false, strId))
{
}
```

I get this exception:

> Could not find a part of the path.

If `strId` is set to something like `localhost\SQLEXPRESS-MyName-2`?

Comment: @paqogomez: Well, I'm not sure why `DirectoryNotFoundException` would be raised when I'm opening  a mutex? There's no connection there...

Comment: If you read his error its: Could not find a part of the path '<mutex name>'.  The answer to the question is your solution as well.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Although, again, it's strange that the directory exception is raised... but, oh well, I guess I'll have to replace slashes...

Comment: As for why its raised, I think @Niels did an excellent job answering that.  `Because you are using a backslash in your name (\) it assumes you are trying to specify a visibility level, and then discovers localhost isn't a valid visibility level - hence generating the exception.`  Good luck :)

Comment: I'm nominating this for reopening since the answer in the other topic is... 'incomplete' to say the least, and rather wildy incorrect to say more.

Comment: Keep in mind that Global\mutexname or Local\mutexname are case sensitive, thus GLOBAL\mutexname will also throw this error because it's all caps.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> On a server that is running Terminal Services, a named system mutex
>   can have two levels of visibility. If its name begins with the prefix
>   "Global\", the mutex is visible in all terminal server sessions. If
>   its name begins with the prefix "Local\", the mutex is visible only in
>   the terminal server session where it was created. In that case, a
>   separate mutex with the same name can exist in each of the other
>   terminal server sessions on the server. If you do not specify a prefix
>   when you create a named mutex, it takes the prefix "Local\". Within a
>   terminal server session, two mutexes whose names differ only by their
>   prefixes are separate mutexes, and both are visible to all processes
>   in the terminal server session. That is, the prefix names "Global\"
>   and "Local\" describe the scope of the mutex name relative to terminal
>   server sessions, not relative to processes.

Because you are using a backslash in your name (`\`) it assumes you are trying to specify a visibility level, and then discovers `localhost` isn't a valid visibility level - hence generating the exception.

It's rather strange the .NET docs don't mention explicitly `\` is a reserved character in Mutex names, the Win32 docs do explain it better ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> The name can have a "Global\" or "Local\" prefix to explicitly create
>   the object in the global or session namespace. **The remainder of the
>   name can contain any character except the backslash character ()**. For
>   more information, see [Kernel Object Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Fast user switching is
>   implemented using Terminal Services sessions. Kernel object names must
>   follow the guidelines outlined for Terminal Services so that
>   applications can support multiple users.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I also referred to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx but there's no explicit mentioning of the slash. They talk about `Global\`, `Local\` and `Session\` prefixes only, so I assumed that as long as I wasn't using those, I'd be OK. Well, evidently not...